Is there a new tool to replace the Saga Polygon Union tool?
In a previous version of QGIS, I used the Saga Polygon Union tool to combine the clipped data from shapefiles containing land use data and shapefiles containing soils data. The overall goal of this was to get a result like this:

Pre-Union Tool:

Shapefile 1 says 5 acres of residential subdivision (RS)
Shapefile 2 says 3 acres of type A soils, 1 acre of type B soils, 4 acres of type C soils, 10 acres of type D soils (net 18 acres)


Post-Union Tool:

Shapefile A says 1 acre of RS with type A soils, 0.5 acres of RS with type B soils, 2 acres of RS with Type C soils, 1.5 acres of type D soils (net 5 acres, equal to what's in the original Shapefile 1 while excluding excess from Shapefile 2).



In a computer update by our IT team, my version of QGIS was updated to 3.34.4-Prizren and I can't find this tool anywhere when I searched for a few different potential names in the Processing Toolbox.
If it's relevant, the previous version I used was 3.2.3 Bonn.
Is there a new tool that replicates this function? Alternately, can someone provide me a step-by-step for how I can duplicate the end result via other methods?

I have the SAGA Vector Polygon Tools - Polygon Union tool in my version which is 3.34.7.  Do you have the other SAGA tools available and usable?  Do you have SAGA available itself in the OsGeo4W folder?  I'm using the Processing Saga NextGen Provider plugin to use SAGA.  I forget at what version SAGA was last supported in the default install.

Also described in QGIS official documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union
There are default Union geoprocessing tools inside Qgis
(Menù -> Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Union)

Union operation with a single input layer with two overlapping features (left) - resulting in four features (middle) - features moved for clarity (right)
In case of 2 Layer the result is described in these image:

Union operation between a two-feature input layer ‘a’ and a single feature overlay layer ‘b’ (left) - resulting five-feature layer with attributes from both layers (right)
With an overlay layer, features on the same layer will not split each other. If you want to split overlaps on the same layer as well as other layers, first run the algorithm with multiple layers then run the algorithm again with only the previous output.

This is a verbatim copying of from the QGIS documentation. Can you advise if this will work to achieve the goal I'm trying for?

In order to use the SAGA-GIS processing algorithm "Polygon union" (and any other SAGA-GIS tool) in QGIS, you need to install the Processing Saga NextGen Provider external third-party plugin in QGIS, provided you have a recent version of SAGA-GIS installed in your system.
